# Issue on variation of a Pascal's Triangle

Tags: python

I am trying to produce a variation of Pascal's Triangle. What I currently have is the code below that will produce a pascal's triangle like this:

```
1 
1 1 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1
```

but I need to produce something like this (with 0 to fill in the empty spots):

```
1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
1 2 1 0
1 3 3 1
```

how should I modify my code to achieve this?
my code is below:

```
n = int(input("Enter number: "))

def chess(row, col):
    if (col ==1): return 1
    if (col ==row): return 1
    upleft = chess(row - 1, col - 1)
    upright = chess(row-1, col)
    return upleft + upright

for r in range (1, n+1):
    for c in range (1, r+1):
        print (chess(r,c), end = " ")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `print ('0 '*(n-r))` after returning the second for loop.

You don't need `print("")` line.

```
for r in range (1, n+1):
    for c in range (1, r+1):
        print (chess(r,c), end = " ")
    print ('0 '*(n-r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last print() statement with:

`print(*([0]*(n-r-1)),sep=" ")`